# Location services issue iPhone.?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, core-location

I am developing an iPhone application.
The problem i am facing is that in start of app i have to present two different views based on either user has enabled or disable location services,But location services alert comes after some seconds.How can i manage it.?
Flow should be like this

App starts  -> locations alert shows - > User press allow -> show deals view

App starts  -> locations alert shows - > User do not allow -> show select location View.

Comment: you have to call your methods in locationmanager update method .so 1st it will show you location alert and after you press button as per your choice you can show your views. dnt call your methods in viewdid load . maybe you are calling it in viewdidload . thats y it happns.

Comment: you can your this delegate method to check user input.     - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status following is statue value kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined
 ,kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted,  
kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied,
kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized.

Answer (score 0):

Use CLLocationManager in the appDelegate to get the locations alert shows in the launch only may be that will help.

Answer (score 0):

Use CLLocationManager with delegate to get the location. If it fails, check the error code to see if the user has denied location access in the app:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    UIAlertView *alert;
    //denied?
    if(error.code == kCLErrorDenied) alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error",@"Error title header") message:NSLocalizedString(@"Turn on Location Services in Settings to use your location",@"Turn on Location Services in Settings to use your location") delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    else alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error",@"Error title header") message:NSLocalizedString(@"At the moment it is not possible to retreive your location",@"At the moment it is not possible to retreive your location") delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```